# Solving an equation with hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to prove that for a given $s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $w\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\cosh(t)e^{i(s+w)}+\sinh(t)e^{i(s-w)}\in\mathbb{R}$.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imaginary part must be zero.
$$\cosh(t)\sin(s+w)+\sinh(t)\sin(s-w)=0$$
$$\cosh(t)\sin(s)\cos(w)+\cosh(t)\cos(s)\sin(w)+\sinh(t)\sin(s)\cos(w)-\sinh(t)\cos(s)\sin(w)=0$$
$$\tan(w)=\frac{\sinh(t)\cos(s)-\cosh(t)\cos(s)}{\cosh(t)\sin(s)+\sinh(t)\sin(s)}=-e^{-2t}\cot(s).$$

Answer (score 0):

you can use this 
$$ \sinh(t) = \frac{e^{t} - e^{-t}}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \cosh(t) = \frac{e^{t} + e^{-t}}{2}$$
to replace in your equation and then use the Euler's form to obtain a Complex number. This new number is in $\mathbb{C}$ and to this is only in $\mathbb{R}$, its imaginary part should be zero. Then you only resolve this new equation and finish your proof.